# unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have been getting this T_IF error, but I can't locate any syntax errors.  Originally I had the ";" inside of the "" for the sql, but after fixing this the errors continued.  I have tried clearing my cache just to be sure that isn't the problem, but no luck.

```
<?php
require_once 'requires-requires.php';
require 'requires-vars.php';

$mainUser = $row[user];

$coinUser = $mainUser;
$coinExperience = 0;
$coinCoins = 0;
$coinLevels = 0;

$coinUser = mysql_real_escape_string($coinUser);
$coinExperience = mysql_real_escape_string($coinExperience);
$coinCoins = mysql_real_escape_string($coinCoins);
$coinLevels = mysql_real_escape_string($coinLevels);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "password";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $usercheck = $conn->query("SELECT user FROM coinchaser WHERE user = '$coinUser'");
    $rows_count_value = mysqli_num_rows($usercheck);

    if($rows_count_value != 0){
        $usernameMatchErr = "You Have Already Joined This Game";
    } else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO coinchaser (user, experience, levels, coins) VALUES ('$coinUser', '$coinExperience', '$coinLevels', '$coinCoins')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
        }
}

?>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>GAMES</h2>
        <p> Game: Description </p>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Coin Chaser">
            </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Added full code from the page.  The $row[user] comes from one of the included files.  This was working prior to me attempting to add the code the below it so I know it is fine.  The issue remains with the following portion of the code:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO coinchaser (user, experience, levels, coins) VALUES ('$coinUser', '$coinExperience', '$coinLevels', '$coinCoins')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

As far as debugging the php, I was having issues attempting to do so on this laptop.  I have been mainly doing javascript/html/css on this laptop and had forgotten that php needed to be installed on it for the debugging to work properly.  I am dusting off my older laptop to see if I can get it to boot up to do a quick php debug on it.

I do plan to put the actual backend operations on their own page.  For some reason, I find it simpler to see it working all together on a single page atm as I am still learning sql and trying to become more familiar and comfortable with it rather than bouncing between two pages back and forth trying to find any syntax errors I might have made.

EDIT (SOLVED): I solved the issue.  I have no idea why, but for some reason it didn't like the database column named "user" being named "user".  My spelling was correct, no syntax issue.  I simply went into the database, changed the column name to "username", returned to the file and change "user" to "username" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: `$coinCoins` seems to supply `levels` and `#coinLevels` seems to supply `coins`.

Comment: Your column list says `levels, coins`, but your values are `$coinCoins, $coinLevels`. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: What does $sql look like?

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for pointing that out.  That will ensure the values go into the correct columns, but it doesn't fix the T_IF issue.  I have been reading stackoverflow after stackoverflow on T_IF issues, but none match what I'm running into yet.

Comment: @jarlh I'm not sure what you are asking for clarification on.  The line showing the $sql = portion is right up there.  =)  What exactly is it you are asking for?

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to a nasty SQL injection attack. Before you do anything else it is ***imperative*** you refactor your code to properly leverage parameterized queries and prepared statements. As it currently stands, there is a high chance that an attacker could exfiltrate or drop all your data with a simple, well-crafted input string.

Comment: Jarlh is asking you to debug the code and supply the Value of `$sql` (after variable substitutions and immediately before execution).

Comment: @esqew Thank you for the words of caution.  I am getting this working first so that I can practice working on those next.  This is a side project for me to learn the in and outs of sql databases and javascript/php interactions.   But, I need to get the foundational code working before I begin messing around with the complex aspects I am trying to learn.  =)

Comment: In any event, please provide the full stack trace of the error in question as well as your code as a [mre]. We can only help you so much without these. [ask]

Comment: @esqew  I have added the full code from the page.  Both the front end and back end aspect are on the same page (I plan to split them later).  I am still learning sql and finding it easier to see how it is working with the code on the same page before I split it.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @MatBailie thank you for explaining that.  I totally get what he meant now.  The debug wasn't working.  I have finally discovered the reason was that I had somehow managed to forget to install php on this pc.  I am having issues trying to get it to install, but did find the zip for it.  So, I'm going to dust off my old laptop and see if it will boot up long enough to debug it.

Comment: I solved the issue.  I have no idea why, but for some reason it didn't like the database column named "user" being named "user".  My spelling was correct, no syntax issue.  I simply went into the database, changed the column name to "username", returned to the file and change "user" to "username" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  I have no idea why, but for some reason it didn't like the database column named "user" being named "user".  My spelling was correct, no syntax issue.  I simply went into the database, changed the column name to "username", returned to the file and change "user" to "username" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: `user` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Thanks =)